# Create static toolbar on webpage that follows scroll in HTML

Tags: html, scroll, toolbar

How do you make a toolbar like object in HTML that follows the user's scroll so that it is always at the top of the viewable page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

css

```
.selector
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

html

```
<div class="selector">
  ... content for bar here ...
</div>
```

Comment: won't this block content underneath it?

Answer (score 11):

Do you specifically need it to scroll (animate) or just a static (toolbar like) object?

EDIT:

Ok so to add a static(toolbar like) object that has a width which is 100% of the page, and a height of say 25px, you would do this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <p>Some content...</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px; /* some styling, please note overall height of the object will be 35px due to 5px padding on top/bottom. */
    background: #ccc; /* some styling */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333; /* some styling */
}
```

Please note that this might overlap any content that you have at the top of the page, so use a top margin to push it down under the toolbar or simply set:

```
body {
    margin-top: 35px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't see the other answer - sorry for the double post.

Comment: That's ok, your answer does help me with the margin though so thanks for that!